# I am facing with an error with delete operation in my core php application

Tags: php, mysql, crud

I have created a small application for php practice. I have successfully created login and insert functionality. I am facing error for delete functionality on dashboard.php.

Login [page](http://thewebtree.in/projects/admin.php).

username: admin
password: 12345

Following is the php code of dashboard.php file:

```
<?php
include 'conntect.php';
    if (isset($_GET['delete'])){
        $del=$_GET['delete'];
        $sql="delete from partners where partner_id=".$del;
        mysqli_query($conn, $sql);
        header('location:dashboard.php');
    }



mysqli_close($conn);
?>
<td><a href="dashboard.php?delete='.$row["partner_id"].'" style="color:red;"><i class="far fa-window-close"></i></a></td>
```

I want to delete the record from database when delete icon is clicked.

Comment: It's really hard to help you if you don't tell us more about the error. What line? What message?

Comment: where is the ```javascript``` or front end codes that table rendering data??show us ;

Comment: Looks like SQL injection. I'd fix it before someone deletes your data...

Comment: PHP Warning:  mysqli_close() expects parameter 1 to be mysqli, null given in /home/thewebtree/public_html/projects/dashboard.php on line 12

Answer (score 0):

Replace your `<td>` for delete with the following code:

```
<td><a href="dashboard.php?delete=<?php echo $row["partner_id"]; ?>" style="color:red;"><i class="far fa-window-close"></i></a></td>
```

And don't close your MySQL connection if `mysqli` is used for further.

Answer (score 0):

You need to share the contents of your "connect.php" file. The reason you are getting the error is becausse "mysqli_query($conn,$sql)" expects parameter 1 to be a (mysqli $link) or a (mysqli $object).

**check this** => (*https://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.query.php*)

**Object oriented style**
mysqli::query ( string $query [, int $resultmode = MYSQLI_STORE_RESULT ] ) : mixed

**Procedural style**
mysqli_query ( mysqli $link , string $query [, int $resultmode = MYSQLI_STORE_RESULT ] ) : mixed

To make a quick fix, you can put this piece of my code in your connect.php file

```
    class Connect {
      private $DB_NAME = 'db_name'; //database name
      private $DB_HOST = 'localhost'; //database host
      private $DB_USER = 'root';  //database user
      private $DB_PASS = ''; //database password
      private $QUERY_DEBUG = 'on'; //enable debug locally and disable in production

      public static $conn;
      public static $pdo_conn;
      
       /**
        constructor function
       **/
       public function __construct() {
            try{
                //initialize a static mysqli connection object or die on error
                self::$conn = new mysqli($this->DB_HOST, $this->DB_USER, $this->DB_PASS, 
                $this->DB_NAME)or 
               die('unable to select Database, Connection Error'.  mysqli_error());
              } catch (Exception $e) {
                 die('unable to select Database, Connection Error'. $e->getMessage());
              }
           /**
             //if you are using pdo, uncomment this block of code
             $pdo = "mysql:host=" . $this->DB_HOST . ";dbname=" . $this->DB_NAME;
             try{
                 self::$pdo_conn = new PDO($pdo, $this->DB_USER, $this->DB_PASS);
             }catch (Exception $e)
             {
                die('unable to select Database, Connection Error'. $e->getMessage());
             }
         **/
       }
      
      /**
        function to encapsulate your queries
      **/
      public function safeQuery($query="") 
     {
        if(empty($query)){return false;}
        if($this->QUERY_DEBUG == "off")//check query debug mode
        {
            //$result = mysqli_query(self::$conn,$query) -> procedural way
            $result = self::$conn->query($query) or 
            die("An error occured");
        }
        else
        {
            //$result = mysqli_query(self::$conn,$query) -> procedural way
            $result = self::$conn->query($query)
            or die("query falied:"."<li>ERROR_NO = ".mysqli_errno(self::$conn)." 
          <li>ERROR= ".  mysqli_error(self::$conn).$query); 
        }
        return $result;
     }
   }
```

Then, to use mysqli queries anywhere in your code, simple do this

```
<?php
   include 'conntect.php';
    $conn = new Connect(); 
    //**Note** $conn exposes a static $conn property(which is a mysqli connection object
    if (isset($_GET['delete'])){
        $del=$_GET['delete'];
        $sql="delete from partners where partner_id=".$del;
        $conn->safeQuery($sql); // (Recommended) Object oriented way
        //mysqli_query($conn::$conn, $sql); // procedural way
        header('location:dashboard.php');
    }



//mysqli_close($conn::$conn);
?>
<td><a href="dashboard.php?delete='.$row["partner_id"].'" style="color:red;"><i class="far fa-window-close"></i></a></td>
```

Answer (score -1):

$sql="DELETE FROM partners WHERE partner_id='{$del}'";